# efficient way of adding default values, where value is not join query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

`teachers`

```
|id|name|
| 1|jhon|
| 2|jane|
| 3| bob|
```

`classes`

```
|id|student_id|hours|teacher_id|
| 1|         1|    1|         1|
| 2|         2|    2|         1|
| 3|         1|    2|         2|
| 4|         1|    2|         2|
```

I want to generate a query that returns the total number of hours and the total students that each teacher has attended

```
|teacher_id|total_students|total_hours|
|         1|             2|          3|
|         2|             1|          4|
|         3|             0|          0|
```

I tried a join on those two tables but it didn't return teachers that had no classes, so i made a union:

```
SELECT teachers.id  AS teacher_id, 
   Sum(classes.hours) AS total_hours, 
   Count(DISTINCT( classes.student_id )) AS total_students 
FROM teachers
   LEFT JOIN classes 
       ON teachers.id = classes.teacher_id 
UNION
SELECT teachers.id, 
   0, 
   0 
FROM teachers 
WHERE  teachers.id NOT IN(SELECT classes.teacher_id FROM classes)
```

Is there a more efficient way to handle this problem?

Comment: Why are you not using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Instead od a union, why not use a left join?

Comment: Classes is a very strange table. This is 1 to 1 tuition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.`id` AS `teacher_id`
    a.`name` AS `teacher_name`,
    COUNT(b.`hours`) AS `total_students`,
    SUM(IFNULL(b.`hours`,0)) AS `total_hours`
FROM `teachers` a
LEFT JOIN `classes` b
ON b.`teacher_id` = a.`id`
GROUP BY a.`id`
ORDER BY a.`id`
```

Comment: thanks I was able to do it this way:

   SELECT
      a.id as teacher_id,
      IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT(b.user_id)), 0) as students,
      IFNULL(SUM(b.used_hours), 0) as total_hours
   FROM
      teachers AS a 
      LEFT JOIN
         classes AS b 
          ON b.teacher_id = a.id 
   GROUP BY
      a.id

Comment: Edit your question, and add what worked - or better yet, add your own answer. Code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: BTW, the IFNULL should be inside the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select teachers.id, coalesce(t.cnt, 0), coalesce(t.hours, 0)  from teachers
left join 
(select sum(hours) as hours, count(distinct student_id) cnt, teacher_id  from classes group by teacher_id) t
on teachers.id = t.teacher_id
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.